# Continuation of the Zeta Function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I already showed that für $\sigma >1$, $$\zeta (s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=1; 2\mid j+1}^{k-1}\left( \prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(s+i) \right) b_{j+1}(0) - \left( \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(s+j)\right) \int_1^{\infty } \frac{b_k(x)}{x^{s+k}},$$ where the $b_i$ are some kind of Bernoulli polynomials.
Now I have to prove that this gives an analytic continuation for the Zeta Function to the half-plane $\sigma >-k+1$. Do I just have to prove that then the integral converges? If so, how can I do this? If not, what else do I have to show?

Comment: What are "some kind of" Bernoulli polynomials?

Comment: $b_1(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor - 1/2$, $b_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^x b_n(y)dy - \int_0^1\int_0^w b_n(y) dy dw$.

Comment: We know $\int_0^1 b_n(y) dy =0$ and $b_n$ is periodic with period 1. Does that imply that $b_n$ is bounded for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, but the upper bound may differ with $n$.

Comment: Ok, so is it just because $b_1$ is bounded and I have $b_{n+1}(x)=\int_0^x b_n(y)dy + c = \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor }^x b_n(y)dy + c \leq C_n(\lfloor x  \rfloor -x ) + c \leq C_n+c$?